# Find the next immediate palindrome of a number

Tags: c++, string, palindrome

The idea of [this problem](https://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/) is to find the immediate next palindrome of a given number. When I submit it to online judge on SPOJ it gives wrong answer. I have tested the code for all possible boundary and exception cases I can think of but still can't figure out which test case my code is failing. I will be very very grateful to you if you can figure out any test case that is not satisfied.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>
#include<cstring>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

bool all_nine(string s,long long size)
{
    long long count=0;
    for(long long i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='9')
            count++;
        else
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void copy(string &low,string &high)
{
    
    long long j=0;
    for(long long i=low.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        high[j]=low[i];
        j++;
    }
   
}

void increment(string &low)
{
    int size=low.length();
    stringstream convert(low);
    long long temp=0;
    convert>>temp;
    temp+=1;
    ostringstream str1;
    str1<<temp;
    low=str1.str();
    if(low.length()<size)
    {
        int temp=size-low.length();
        string s1;
        for(int i=0;i<temp;i++)
        {
            s1+="0";
        }
        low=s1+low;
    }
}

string find_next_palindrome(string s)
{
    //cout<<s;
    long long size=s.length();
    //cout<<"size:"<<size;
    if(all_nine(s,size))
    {
        s[0]='1';
        for(long long i=1;i<size;i++)
            s[i]='0';
        s+='1';
        return s;
    }
    else if(size%2==0)
    {
        string low,high;
        long long mid=size/2;
    
        for(long long i=0;i<mid;i++)
            low+=s[i];
        for(long long i=mid;i<size;i++)
            high+=s[i];
        
        if((long long)s[mid-1]>(long long)s[mid])
        {
            copy(low,high);
        }
        else if((long long)s[mid-1]<(long long)s[mid])
        {
            increment(low);
            copy(low,high);
        }
        else
        {
            long long temp_low=mid-1;
            long long temp_high=mid;
            while(temp_low!=0 && temp_high!=size-1)
            {
                if((long long)s[temp_low]>(long long)s[temp_high])
                    break;
                temp_low--;
                temp_high++;
            }
            if((long long)s[temp_low]>(long long)s[temp_high])
            {
                copy(low,high);
            }
            else
            {
                increment(low);
                copy(low,high);
            }
        }
        return low+high;
    }
    else
    {
        string low,high;
        long long mid=size/2;
        
        for(long long i=0;i<mid;i++)
            low+=s[i];
        for(long long i=mid+1;i<size;i++)
            high+=s[i];
            
        if((long long)s[mid-1]>(long long)s[mid+1])
        {
            copy(low,high);
        }
        else if((long long)s[mid-1]<(long long)s[mid+1])
        {
            if(s[mid]=='9')
            {
                s[mid]='0';
                
                increment(low);
                
                copy(low,high);
            }
            else
            {
                s[mid]=((s[mid]-'0')+1)+'0';
                copy(low,high);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            long long temp_low=mid-1;
            long long temp_high=mid+1;
            while(temp_low!=0 && temp_high!=size-1)
            {
                if((long long)s[temp_low]!=(long long)s[temp_high])
                    break;
                temp_low--;
                temp_high++;
            }
            if((long long)s[temp_low]>(long long)s[temp_high])
            {
                
                copy(low,high);
            }
            else
            {
                if(s[mid]=='9')
                {
                    s[mid]='0';
                    increment(low);
                    copy(low,high);
                }
                else
                {
                    s[mid]=((s[mid]-'0')+1)+'0';
                    copy(low,high);
                }
            }
            
        }
        return (low+s[mid]+high);
    }
}
int main()
{
    long long t;
    cin>>t;
    vector<string> v(t);
    for(long long i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        string temp;
        cin>>temp;
        v[i]=temp;
    }

    //cout<<"\n"<<"\n";
    for(long long i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        if(v[i].length()==1)
        {
            if(v[i]=="9")
                cout<<"11"<<endl;
            else
                cout<<(v[i][0]-'0')+1<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            string str=find_next_palindrome(v[i]);
            for(long long j=0;j<str.length();j++)
                cout<<str[j];
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test input:

```
40
808
2133
9999999
999999
899998
3423355356
100001
46887767
9
99
0
1991
1239400
123999500
56442
56471
123456
1234567
77777777777
2991
3994
9999
5448
653434
101
199
0012100
0003
123456
1234567
9999
99999
1
2991
3994
9999
5448
65343454
100
4111
```

Expected output:

```
818
2222
10000001
1000001
900009
3423443243
101101
46888864
11
101
1
2002
1240421
124000421
56465
56565
124421
1235321
77777877777
2992
4004
10001
5555
654456
111
202
0013100
0110
124421
1235321
10001
100001
2
2992
4004
10001
5555
65344356
101
4114
```

My program gives the expected output, so I can't figure out why it is marked as not correct. Is there another case not covered in the model input for which my program doesn't give the correct answer?

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve] including both input (preferably hardcoded), expected output and actual output. Make sure it compiles without warning. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Looks fine to me. Seems to cover all the cases.

Comment: asking for "a minimal reproducible example" makes no sense in this case: that's essentially the question...

Comment: Let me paraphrase this Q: "I have code here and I have tests that show that the code is correct. Someone says it's not correct, so what is the error?" The simple answer is: "Ask the one that said it's wrong." Sorry, but questions with online judges that don't tell people what they consider wrong are notoriously useless here, because they involve guessing what some third, unknown code does.